# Cumulative product conditionally using Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to cumulate the **backward** product of the rates between the values (column value). I tried this function `df.groupby('id')['rate'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])` but does the cumulate all rates.

**My dataframe:**

```
data = {
        'id': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
        'year':  [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
        'value': [0, 11927, 0, 10355, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12020],
        'rate': [0.998, 0.989, 0.998, 1.019, 1.011, 1.011, 0.984, 0.988, 0.988, 1.006, np.nan]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

```
df.loc[df.value==0, 'rate_product_cumul'] = df.groupby(['id']).rate\
                                              .transform(lambda x: x[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])
```

**Result:**

[image]

**What I m looking for:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df['rate_product_cumul'] = df.groupby(['id', df['value'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()])['rate']\
                             .apply(lambda x: x[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])
```

Output:

```
     id  year  value   rate  rate_product_cumul
0   100  2008      0  0.998            0.998000
1   100  2009  11927  0.989            0.989000
2   100  2010      0  0.998            0.998000
3   100  2011  10355  1.019            1.019000
4   100  2012      0  1.011            0.987664
5   100  2013      0  1.011            0.976918
6   100  2014      0  0.984            0.966289
7   100  2015      0  0.988            0.982001
8   100  2016      0  0.988            0.993928
9   100  2017      0  1.006            1.006000
10  100  2018  12020    NaN                 NaN
```

You need to create a temporary group key for every time 'value' changes using `diff`, `ne` and `cumsum`.